# Getting the name of the foreign key with eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

This must be very basic stuff but I can't seem to find out how to do it.

I have a one to many relationship between to tables: Unit and Army (an army contains many units) and these are my models:

```
class Army extends Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $armies = array();

    protected $table = 'armies';

    public function units()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Unit');
    }

}
```

and:

```
class Unit extends Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $units = array();

    protected $table = 'units';

    public function armies()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Army', 'army');
    }


}
```

So, in my Unit table I have a row called"army" that contains the id of the army related to that unit and I want to show in my view a simple ul list in the following fashion (I want this to show on the unit index view):

```
 <ul>
      <li>Army 1 name
           <li>Unit 1 of Army 1</li>
           <li>Unit 2 of Army 1</li>
      </li>
      <li>Army 2 name
           <li>Unit 1 of Army 2</li>
           <li>Unit 2 of Army 2</li>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

To do this I have my unit controller like so:

```
class UnitsController extends BaseController {

protected $layout = 'master';

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $units = Unit::all();

    $this->layout->content = View::make('units.index', compact('units'));


}
/*Other stuff*/
}
```

And in my view (index.blade.php inside views/units):

```
<ul class="units">
    @foreach($units as $unit)
        {{$unit->army}}
            <li>        
        {{ HTML::link(route('units.show', ['units' => $unit->id]), $unit->name)}}
    </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

But {{$unit->army}} is just (of course) showing the id of the army, and I want the name, how do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have set up your schema correctly: **armies** table has at least **id**(auto-increment) and **units** table has at least **id**(auto-increment) and **army_id** (integer, unsigned), then, try this:

**Models**

```
class Army extends Eloquent {
   public function units()
   {
     return $this->hasMany('Unit');
   }
}


class Unit extends Eloquent {
  public function armies()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Army');
  }
}
```

**In your Controller**
You want to *get* all *armies with units*:

```
$armies = Army::with('units')->get();
```

**In your View** you want to loop through the result set outputting the name of each army and its respective units

```
@foreach($armies as $army)
    {{$army->name}}
       <ul>
          @foreach($army->units as $aunit)
            <li>        
               {{ $aunit->name }}
            </li>
          @endforeach
       </ul>
@endforeach
```

If that doesn't work, I'll eat my head.

Comment: the tables are as you described but I have "army" instead of "army_id" but that's why I have return $this->belongsTo('Army', 'army'); and I assume it's working since the id is showing correctly. I'll try your approach in a minute.

Comment: Yeah that was what I was missing, I was looking at the problem backwards, thanks :)

Comment: Yes, there was a problem there. Actually you don't have to state the name of the primary key field if it's what laravel expects (**army_id**) (as I did in my solution). Please let me know if it actually worked.

Comment: It did work, but now I need to do the same with another table and I don't know how to combine it with this, I've started a new question since this one is technically answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943446/how-to-relate-one-table-with-others-using-eloquent-orm

Comment: Have a look at the **controller** and **view** in my answer. You can have whatever information you want in the units table and you can just pull it out the same way I have pulled the unit name in my view. So, you don't need a third table! You chose my answer without really going through it!

Comment: no no, I actually implemented it in my site and did exactly what I needed but I have a third table called unittype that has extra info and needs to show up aswell in the unit view, and adding it to the query made a mess of what I already had

Comment: Ok, do you still need to maintain the markup in your views as stated in your question?

Comment: It would be something like: Army name - Unittype inside the army (unrelated to it) - list of units of said army that are part of that unittype

Comment: Should I merge the other question with this one?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31314/discussion-between-kjamesy-and-elaine-marley)